# CodeIgniter : call a controller function within another instance

Tags: codeigniter

I have 2 instances of codeigniter and I would like to call a function of an instance from the other instance. I have a first instance that deals with accounts (in mywebsite.com/account.php) and a second dealing with stock portfolios (mywebsite.com/portfolio.php). The aim would be that when I register a new position in my portfolio, it will register the fees in the account instance.

In account.php, I have a controller to add a transaction (account.php/transaction/add).
In portfolio.php, I have a controller to add a new position (portfolio.php/position/add).

I want to call account.php/transaction/add with some arguments (maybe in POST method) within the controller portfolio.php/position/add. Is there a simple way to do it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to address this need. When some functionality is needed in more than controller that points to creating a resource that both controllers can load and use.

The "resource" might be a model, or it might be a custom "library", or maybe both. (It should NOT be some other controller.) The answer depends on exactly what has to happen. Since you don't share any code it's impossible to offer precise help.

Since I have to guess that guess is that a model used by both controllers could work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. You are right, I will try to be more accurate with some codes.

Basically, when I add a new position in my portfolio (eg: I buy 50 shares of a stock AAA), I register it in my website portfolio.php. But at the same time, I would like to register a transaction in account.php with the fees paid.

Here is the code of the portfolio.php/position/add :

```
public function add()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('portfolio', 'Portfolio', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Type', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view(SHARED_VIEWS_FOLDER.'header', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('menu', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('transaction/add', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('menu_bottom', $this->data);
        $this->load->view(SHARED_VIEWS_FOLDER.'footer', $this->data);
    } else {
        $the_quantity=$this->input->post('quantity');
        if ($this->input->post('type') == "sell") {$the_quantity = -$the_quantity;}
        $this->position_model->addTransaction($this->input->post('portfolio'), $this->input->post('stock'), $the_quantity, $this->input->post('price'), $this->input->post('fees'), $this->input->post('date'));

        //TO DO : ADD THE TRANSACTION IN ACCOUNT.PHP


        redirect(base_url().'stock.php/transaction', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

The aim is to send some parameters (date, fees, stock, price) to account.php in order to add a transaction. I was thinking about calling a controller such as account.php/transaction/add, but it can also be to call directly the model transaction_model.php.

In the end, I want it to behave like an API: portfolio.php is calling an API in account.php, send some parameters and it will create a transaction in account.php.